# Android Animation: change speed

Tags: android, animation

I have implemented an animation in Android.
This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-4%p"
        android:toXDelta="4%p"
        android:repeatCount="2"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

But the speed of moving is a little slow. How can I increase speed?
I have tried also the `accelerate_interpolator` but it's too slow......

Thanks

PS: The movement that I want to do is like a cut of a knife.
So I want to move it ahead and behind some times.

Comment: try to decrease duration.

Comment: You have right, it's better. I don't think it was so simple. I reduce the time and increase the count. thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Decrease the duration you have result in front of you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-4%p"
        android:toXDelta="4%p"
        android:repeatCount="2"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="10" />
</set>
```

Comment: Happy coding !!